# SCRIPT458: Variable uses an automation type not supprted in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run an html page containing VBScript for IE 11. 
I took this snippet of code which is supposedly working, and tried to run it. However, the IE11 inspector always highlights the following error:

> SCRIPT458: Variable uses an Automation Type not supported in VBScript: 'bl.A'

Thanks to this error code, I identified that the error is related to the instruction:

> Set bl.A(arg1, 2) = s

I call the vbscript function `getAddr` from a javascript call in the same page. The associated source code is the following:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
    Dim bl
    Dim plunge(32)
    Dim y(32)
    Class ArrayWrapper
        Dim A
        Private Sub Class_Initialize
            ' 2x2000 elements x 16 bytes / element = 64000 bytes
            ReDim Preserve AA(1, 2000)
            A = AA
        End Sub
        Public Sub Resize()
            ReDim Preserve A(1, 1)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class Spray
    End Class

    Function getAddr (arg1, s)
        bl = Null
        Set bl = New ArrayWrapper
        For i = 0 To 32
            Set plunge(i) = s
        Next
        Set bl.A(arg1, 2) = s
        Dim addr
        Dim i
        For i = 0 To 31
            If Asc(Mid(y(i), 3, 1)) = VarType(s) Then
                addr = strToInt(Mid(y(i), 3 + 4, 2))
            End If
            y(i) = Null
        Next
        If addr = Null Then
            document.location.href = document.location.href
            Return
        End If
        getAddr = addr
    End Function

    Function function_calling_getAddr (arg1)
        Dim addr
        ' Create a vbscript class instance
        Set sp = New Spray
        ' Get address of the class instance
        addr = getAddr(arg1, sp)
        ' .....
    End Function        

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Dim addr
    ' Create a vbscript class instance
    Set sp = New Spray

    var o;
    o = {"valueOf": function () {
            triggerBug();
            return 1;
        }};
    setTimeout(function() {function_calling_getAddr(o);}, 50);

</script>
```

I really don't know what to do to solve this issue... Would you have any clue?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That last `<script>` section is not VBScript, are you sure you've copied into the post correctly? The line and preceding lines from `var o;` are not valid VBScript syntax, they look more like client-side JavaScript.

Comment: sorry, you're right, the function is called from a javascript call. I updated the code. Thank for your comment!

Comment: David, it's more, the last code block and the last `<script>` tag I was referring to, you seem to have a mix of VBScript and JavaScript.

Comment: You are perfectly right! I made a copy mistake as the code was on another workstation :/ I also wanted to be more synthetic so that it be the lightest as possible. Thank you for your comment!